# Regex to match various patterns

Tags: regex, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to create a regex to catch a number of possible strings and then assign it to a new name, the regex acts as a filter.

The code I have has three options for the disks such as `vm01-disk2 or vm01-disk-2 or vm01-disk_2`

I've created a If loop as below

```
$newname = vm02
        elseif ($vhdrename -match 'disk[-_]?2' -or $vhdrename -match 'disk[-_]?-2' -or $vhdrename -match 'disk[-_]?_2') {
        $vhdname = "$newname-datadisk02"
        }
        elseif ($vhdrename -match 'disk[-_]?3' -or $vhdrename -match 'disk[-_]?-3' -or $vhdrename -match 'disk[-_]?_3') {
        $vhdname = "$newname-datadisk03"
        }
```

However it only works if the disk name is vm01-disk2 and misses disk_2 and disk-2.

There are around disks per VM that i will need to loop through and several 100 disks, hence the need for an automated solution :(

I've tried

```
    elseif ($vhdrename -match 'disk[-_]_?4') {
    $vhdname = "$newname-datadisk04"
    Write-Host "VM name is"$vhdname -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    elseif ($vhdrename -match 'disk[-_]-4') {
    $vhdname = "$newname-datadisk04"
    Write-Host "VM name is"$vhdname -ForegroundColor red
    }
```

Also escaping characters such as `'disk[-_]\-4'`

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong and I'm sure there's a neater and smarter way of doing this, I'm just not seeing it :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [1] if is not a loop structure. [*grin*] ///// [2] where is the IF? you show `elseif` but don't show the `if` it is part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the character class optional, and for example use capture groups to make decisions for the ForegroundColor and to concat the digits with `datadisk`

```
\bdisk([-_]?)([0-9]+)
```

- `\bdisk` Match `disk`
- `([-_]?)` Optionally capture either `-` or `_` in group 1
- `([0-9]+)` capture group 2, match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A1suRM/1)

Comment: Thanks and Ive just tried this `'disk[-_]?([4])'` an it's not captured `vm01-disk-4` did I do something wrong?

Comment: @NorrinRad Did you use $Matches? See [this example](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyW4pEjBVkG9LNfAUDclszhb10SdSyUgsaQktSgPJBGTBBLViNaNj7XX1Ig20LWM1dYEKslNLEnOACoAG6AL4cH0cXGFF2WWpOp65BeXKEBUooj4gkRSi6MNYrEKG2IXNor9/x8A)

Comment: that was a great helps and it's also helped me identify where I could have been going wrong, I've got a split and thats splitting at "-" or "_"  so disk-4 or disk_4 becomes just disk. do you know a way i can have all the disk name types included, currently it's set as `($snapshot.name).Split([char[]]'-_')[1]`

Comment: @NorrinRad If you mean the name before the `-` then you might use another capture group `(\w+)-disk([-_]?)([0-9]+)` https://regex101.com/r/J9lTCn/1 Then you could check the capture group values like this [for example](https://tio.run/##RY3BCoJAEIbv@xRDCKvIgFmXDtEhiC5B0KGDSSztlJK6tW56CJ/d3EXpP8xh/vm@eamWdJ1RUfS9dzIa1sCbMpqjzOsnLjnzjsIY0pUt/EsbBq7xE7ymm8BPIlylYTCcVdRWoqSRjzlj@R18p8RSmFsGkymALwxhdnhNJkdsNilQCiPskxmE4B0sS3WySB3gpNMuTgHpDRz54HS1zVnnhnCvavPX405pemj1qeRWFUqDJumADljX9z8)